# Ways of solving recurrence relation for $a(15)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have this recurrence relation:

$$
R(1)=1, RE(1)=0, EE(1)=0$$

$$a(n)=R(n) + RE(n)$$

$$R(n)=EE(n-1)+RE(n-1),$$$$ RE(n)=R(n-1),$$$$ EE(n)=RE(n-1)
$$

How do I get $a(15)$?
What kind of method do I use?

Comment: try to calculate some values after 1 for RE, R and EE (meaning, calculate R(n) and RE(n) and EE(n) for n=2,3,4) and try to find some consistency. What do you find about R and RE? (which you need for a)? how can you use that to calculate it for n=15?

Answer (score 1):

$$R(n)=EE(n-1)+RE(n-1)=RE(n-2)+RE(n-1)=R(n-3)+R(n-2) \,.$$
$$RE(n)=R(n-1)=EE(n-2)+RE(n-2)=RE(n-3)+RE(n-2) \,.$$

Adding them you get

$$a(n)=a(n-3)+a(n-2) \,.$$

Solve it!

Comment: thank you very much, i got the answer. :)

just another question for my knowledge: how do i create a function to immediately find a(15) instead of checking the whole way to it through a(1)...??

thanks in advance

Comment: @user76508 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $EE(n)$ from the last equation:

$$R(n)=RE(n-2)+RE(n-1).$$

Then substitute $RE(n)$:

$$R(n)=R(n-3)+RE(n-2) \ \ \ (1)$$

$$a(n)=R(n) + R(n-1) \ \ \ (2)$$

Now solve the recurrent equation ($1$) and then  ($2$).